# Router instances in Node.js with express with a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

As far as I can gather from the [Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html), when you declare an `express.Router()`, it creates a single instance of a router that you can then assign a routing path and execute logic with. The documentation says to think of a router like a mini-app for a specific route or routes, which makes sense.

I'm trying to strategize what to wrap my database connection around (using mongodb, let's say via mongoose, but it shouldn't matter). I of course don't want to open a new database connection on every route call, and I assume that if I wrap it around a router only one `Router()` instance will only be created. In other words, if I went to `/routes/index.js`, defined a `Router()` and then opened a database connection, then within it did `router.get` (or `router.post`, etc.), I would be opening one database connection when launching the app, not one per hit on that route.

Yet there might be other routes beyond `index.js` where I want access to the database. So alternatively, could I wrap the database connection around the `app.use` route handlers and other middleware within the main `app.js` file, then `require('../app')` in `/routes` files and add the database connection to `module.exports` in `app.js`, and finally define route logic in other files like `/routes/index.js`?

I'm a little confused on how to structure everything. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not let the database library handle database connection pooling? Create a file (`db.js` or something) that exports the connection pool `connPool`. In your route handlers, `const db = require('./db'); db.connPool.getConnection()` or something similar would get you a db connection.

Comment: I'm attempting to implement this now. It would appear to be working. I have a `./database/db.js` file with a `getConnection` function that has the `mongoose.connect` inside it, all assigned to `connPool`. `connPool` is then exported. To test, within `app.js` I declare `const db = require('./database/db');` then around where I define middlewares I have `db.getConnection()`. Now when I want to access the db from route handlers I can use the same structure. Just want to be sure I'm not going to open a lot of db connections here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using mongoose, you can just connect once with some code like this:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test");
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Db connection error:'));
// Start the server once we have connected to the database.
mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Db connection open.');
    app.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log('Listening on port 3000');
    });
});
```

And then, if you have a mongoose model named `Foo` set up like

```
const Foo = mongoose.model('Foo', fooSchema); // fooSchema is a  mongoose.Schema
```

Then in your route you can use it like so:

```
const router = express.Router();
const Foo = require('./models/foo');
router
    .route('/foos/:foo_id')
    .get((req, res)=> {
        Foo.findById(req.params.foo_id, (err, foo) => {
        if (err) return res.sendStatus(500);
        if (!foo) return res.status(404).send('Foo not found.');
        res.status(200).json(foo);
    });
});
```

This kind of setup lets mongoose handle connection pooling.

Comment: This works quite well, thanks! Just in case anyone else as inexperienced as I am looks at this later, put the mongoose connection part in the main app file after the middlewares. I defined my model in `./models/foo`, and I have routes under `./routes/foo`. So for me it the route part was const `Foo = require('../models/foo');`. Also mongoose throws a deprecation warning that can be solved simply by setting options for the connection http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html